# Trigger auto-complete halfway a word in brackets IDE

Tags: autocomplete, adobe-brackets, hints

Is it possible to trigger autocompletion in Brackets when you're in the middle of the word? When I start a new word it will trigger and show all the possibilities but after a typo and a backspace I lose this list. Is there a way to enable auto-completion so that it is always suggesting possible matches?

Answer (score 2):

**Ctrl + Space.** Most of the IDE support this for auto completion.

Comment: Yes that works thank you, but I'm also looking for a solution that just shows the possible completions without having to press a shortcut

Comment: @Deb Try updating to newer version I am using the latest for windows it shows without pressing any keys.

Comment: does it also show up when it went away after a typo and a backspace to correct that typo?

Answer (score 0):

when i press Ctrl + Space without pressing any keys try to trigger auto suggest possible option, it doesn't work, cause the mac shortcuts setting use Ctrl + Space to change input source. you can change the mac shortcuts setting or the IDE keymap setting

Mac shortcuts setting

[image: 1]

IDE keymap setting

[image: 2]